# C++ program: Printing a trapezoid using input redirection

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print a trapezoid, but for some reason it's either I keep getting a triangle, or the size of my trapezoid is wrong. Can someone please tell me what's wrong or what's missing? Your help is greatly appreciated. 
Is there a way I can input my own values for the top row/base, and the height? I input my height, and I don't get right height.

```
for (i = 1; i < trapeH; i++)
{
    for (k = spacesT-1; k > 0; k--)
    {
        cout << " ";
    }

    spacesT = spacesT - 1;

    for (j = 1; j <= (2*i + 1); j++)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: What are you setting `trapeH` and `spacesT` to be at the start?

Comment: Please provide us some sample input and what you expect the trapezoid to look like based on that.

Answer (score 1):

What are your input-values for `trapeH` and `spacesT`?

I used 10 for both and got following output:

```
         ***
        *****
       *******
      *********
     ***********
    *************
   ***************
  *****************
 *******************
```

So it seems to work - it's an trapezoid

---

Here is the corrected source there your parameters are the height and the width of the top row:

```
void trapezoid (int width, int height)
{
   for (int row = 0; row < height; ++row) {
      for (int col = height - row; col > 0; --col) {
         cout << " ";
      }
      for (int col = 0; col < (width + 2 * row); ++col) {
         cout << "*";
      }
      cout << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to input a value for the top row & and height, but when I change the height or 'trapeH' it doesn't give me the right height. 'spaceT' I placed in the code to count print out blank spaces to form the trapezoid.

Comment: so you want to have the length of top row (count of stars) and the height as input-variables (instead trapeH and spacesT) ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. 
@Nathanael Oh ok. Thank you for the clarification. 

Please bare with me as I'm still a beginner at programming.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (j=1; j <=(2*i+1); j++)
```

This line guarantees your trapezoid will always start at width 3 and grow by two *'s each line. If you want a variable width trapezoid, you need to introduce an additional variable.

But as MacGucky pointed out, you do have a trapezoid.

EDIT:

The height of your trapezoid will be trapeH - 1. If you set trapeH = 10, you'll go through the loop 9 times since i = 10 will cause the loop to quit.